# Is it possible to post in open Facebook group and make one of my friends won't see this post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I want to publish in an open group in Facebook and make sure that one of my friends won't see this posts.

How can I do this? If I will block this friend, will he also be able to see my posts there?

(Maybe he liked this group and maybe not.)

Comment: sorry... fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an open group and he/she subscribes to it, yes he will see the posts.
Blocking the person is an option.

<sub>The correct option is not writing posts behind friends' backs</sub>